# statsmodel: ZeroInflatedPoisson gives nan, ZeroInflatedGeneralizedPoisson paras are inconsistent

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels, poisson

I have an 1-D data, which is a zero inflated count data. So, I try to fit a zero-inflated possion model to get a estimated distribution. I tried with my true data and synthetic data on different models using `statsmodels`. However, it gives strange results.

Statsmodels is not well documented, here is [the official guide of statsmodels.discrete.count_model](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/discretemod.html?highlight=statsmodels%20discrete%20count_model#module-statsmodels.discrete.count_model)

## Question 1, ZeroInlatedPossion gives `nan` pmf

I want to fit an zero-inflated possion model and then perform a KS-test between data and fitted distribution. However, on synthetic dataset, `frozen_dist.pmf(1)` give `nan`.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
from statsmodels.discrete.count_model import ZeroInflatedPoisson,ZeroInflatedGeneralizedPoisson,ZeroInflatedNegativeBinomialP

data = stats.bernoulli.rvs(p = 0.4, size = 2000, random_state = 42)*\
stats.poisson.rvs(mu = 5, size = 2000, random_state = 42)
# data1 = np.array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 15.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
#         0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  1.,  0.,  1.,
#         0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
#         0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])

zip_model = ZeroInflatedPoisson(endog = data, exog= np.ones_like(data)) # clarify a model
zip_res = zip_model.fit() # fit model with data to estimate distribution parameters
frozen_dist = zip_model.distribution(*zip_res.params) # frozen a distribution
frozen_dist.pmf(1) # fitted with data, it gives nan; fitted with data1, it gives real values
# stats.kstest(data1, frozen_dist.cdf)
```

Output:

> nan

## Question 2, ZeroInflatedGeneralizedPoisson can not frozen a distribution with fitted params

```
# zigp model params did not consistent with zigp_model.distribution
data = stats.bernoulli.rvs(p = 0.4, size = 2000, random_state = 42)*\
stats.poisson.rvs(mu = 5, size = 2000, random_state = 42)
# data1 = np.array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 15.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
#         0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  1.,  0.,  1.,
#         0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
#         0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])

zigp_model = ZeroInflatedGeneralizedPoisson(endog = data, exog= np.ones_like(data))
zigp_res = zigp_model.fit()
frozen_dist = zigp_model.distribution(*zip_res.params) # Error in this step
stats.kstest(data, frozen_dist.cdf)
```

Output:

> TypeError: _parse_args() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'p' and 'w'

Answer (score 0):

The parameters for the zeroinflated poisson distribution should be the mean (mu) followed by the proportion of zeros (w). The distribution method is from statsmodels.distributions and you can check the [source code](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/main/statsmodels/distributions/discrete.py). Yes not very well documented

So using a example like yours:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
from statsmodels.discrete.count_model import ZeroInflatedPoisson

data = stats.bernoulli.rvs(p = 0.4, size = 2000, random_state = 42)*\
stats.poisson.rvs(mu = 30, size = 2000, random_state = 42)

zip_model = ZeroInflatedPoisson(endog = data, exog= np.ones_like(data)) 
zip_res = zip_model.fit()
```

The first term of params is the zero inflation part, the second is your poisson mu :

```
zip_res.summary()

                    coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
inflate_const     0.3702      0.045      8.137      0.000       0.281       0.459
const             3.3944      0.006    529.596      0.000       3.382       3.407

zip_res.params
array([0.37017071, 3.39436043])
```

Now we make the distribution and you can see it's correct.

```
frozen_dist = zip_model.distribution(mu = zip_res.params[1], w= zip_res.params[0]) 
frozen_dist.pmf(1)

0.07175113976309205
```

Likewise you just flip your second fit.